# How does $R[f^{-1}]$ differ from $R_f$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, definition, localization

In the book "The geometry of schemes" I ran into the notation $R[f^{-1}]$, where $R$ is a ring, and $f\in R$. I have to admit that I never quite got the precise meaning of $R[f^{-1}]$ and how it differs from $R_f$, the localisation of $R$ at $\{1,f,f^2,\dots\}$.

To me the notation $R[f^{-1}]$ is a bit unclear, especially since there is no clear "ambient" ring around in which $f^{-1}$ is defined. Unlike for example the case of adjoining a root to a field, where we can find the root in an algebraic closure. So without some bigger ring in which we have an element $f^{-1}$, what entity does the $f^{-1}$ in $R[f^{-1}]$ even refer to? To me the most logical interpretation would be to $f^{-1}\in R_f$, but then I would say that $R[f^{-1}]\cong R_f$, so that the notation is redundant.

Either way I feel like I must be overlooking something, so I would appreciate it if someone could shine some light on this.

Comment: The ambient ring could be the quotient field (if $R$ is a domain) and if not the total quotient ring of $R$.

Comment: They do denote the same ring, up to isomorphism. Note that in $R_f$, the elements are of the form $(a,b)$ with $a,b\in R$ (specifically with $b=f^i$ for some natural $i$), while the elements of $R[f^{-1}]$ are of the form $a_0+a_1f^{-1}+\cdots+a_nf^{-n}$ with $a_i\in R$. However, what you _mean_ by $f^{-1}$ is best described in terms of the localisation (as $(1,f)\in R_f$), so in the end, maybe they're exactly the same thing after all?

Comment: @Arthur Do you have any idea why the author would use $R_f$ in some instances and $R[f^{-1}]$ in others?

Comment: On the notation, not sure if this is the reason for the choice. The notation $R_f$ can be amibigous. Some authors denote by $R_p$ the localization at $p$, for $p$ prime, which is however the quotient ring with respect to the set  $R \setminus (p)$. (Leaving aside it could even  also be the completion.)   Thus one might feel "$R$ subscript element"  is overloaded and thus avoid it.

Comment: Because they felt like it? As I said, the biggest difference is the canonical form of a generic element, so maybe some times it pays to think about it one way and some times the other? @quid There's a difference between "$R$ subscript element" and "$R$ subscript prime ideal", so it's not quite overloaded, but that might be it too.

Comment: @quid Thing is, that just a couple of sentences earlier the author did use the notation $R_f$ (thereby causing my confusion)

Comment: Where exactly in the book does it show up this example?

Comment: @quid bottom of page 21

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I have no clear idea what might have motivated it there. I'd  think as well these are two equivalent ways to express the same concept.

Comment: @quid Thanks for taking a look! I'll just take it to mean $R_f$ then, since that seems sensible and everybody here agrees.

Comment: There is one real difference that I just realised (don't know whether it's relevant): If $f$ is a zero divisor, the meaning of $R_f$ is intuitively clearer than the meaning of $R[f^{-1}]$: If $gf=0$, then $g$ becomes zero in the localisation by construction, but it is not so obvious that $g\in R[f^{-1}]$ is zero.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean by "$R_f$ being intuitively clearer". The localisation construction doesn't care. In fact, the possibility of the multiplicatively closed subset $S\subseteq R$ containing zero divisors is why the phrase "$(a,b)\sim (c,d)$ iff $\exists t\in S$ such that $t(ad-bc)=0$" in the definition of localisation has the $t$ in there.